# If I download a hacked Joomla website on my laptop to fix it

Tags: security, joomla

If I download a hacked website on my laptop to fix it and I run php code that someone else could have modified, am I going to risk to damage my local computer?

Let's say I need to assign some privileges to run a mysql database this could be potentially dangerous right?

It is a hacked Joomla website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot be sure what can happen. For maximum protection, I recommend putting everything in a virtual machine and then disable its internet access.

Answer (score 1):

That depends.

If hacker put some malicious script(js\html) that use vulnerabilities in browser, or something similar, than you may damage your machine.

Usually modified php's provide backdoors, also known as shells, or provide proxies, or something similar. They are used for remote access, and are not usually intended to broke the machine. However, that's not always true.

If your site was running under unix environment, and your laptop runs Windows, the risk is lesser.

I would recommend at least using firewall. For full protection, you should **do anything inside a virtual machine.**

Use any compare tool to find modified places.

As for database, use only local copy. When you've corrected everything, replace the version on the server with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a risk: the PHP code will have the same permissions as the user running the code on the computer. If you give the PHP code access to a database, it will be able to do anything the MySQL user can do.

If you're going for 100% safety, run all of it in a virtual machine to avoid accidents with your actual laptop.

**Update**: of course, a good first step would be to diff the PHP code with the Joomla! official PHP code of the appropriate version, to identify differences between the two.

Answer (score 1):

When code has been modified by someone else, running/executing it is always dangerous. Therefore, you must take care that it can't be executed:

1. Don't download with a web browser. Use a tool that just makes a binary copy like `rsync`, `wget` or log into your server, create a ZIP archive of the modified scripts and then download that.
2. Always make a backup copy of everything before you look at it. That includes the database, all scripts, HTML pages, templates, everything.
3. Run the code on an isolated computer (no network connection). If you don't have a spare laptop, run it in a virtual machine with networking turned off. This isn't as secure as the first option because virtual machines have bugs, too, but it's better than nothing.
4. Never execute the code unless you know it's safe. First, compare it against a know good copy. If there isn't one, read the code and try to figure out what it does. If that's beyond your limits, mark it down as experience, scrap the whole thing and start from scratch.

   You don't want users of your site to sue you when they get hacked because you failed to remove all the malicious code, do you?
5. The bad code might not be in the scripts; if your site is vulnerable to [script injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection), then it can be in the database and only be visible when the pages are rendered. If this is the case, fix all places where database values are pasted into the HTML verbatim before you try to view them in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla hacks are usually pretty straight forward (but time consuming) to clean up (old Joomla versions can be pretty venerable to attack), follow some of the tips here to keep your self safe and remember to:

Replace all the Joomla system files with the latest version from Joomla!

If you have a fairly recent backup it would be much easier to just remove the hacked site and restore the backup, and then update it to the latest version of Joomla to help secure it.

Comment: This may not solve the problem completely. Hackers could left a shellcode not only in joomla files (there's a trick with putting it inside image file and modifying .htaccess for that dir, for instance)